# How to target element by type and class

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, getelementsbytagname

I am attempting to create a function using only vanilla JS which will resize fonts in a container with a given class. Found [this demo](https://coderwall.com/p/_8jxgw/autoresize-text-to-fit-into-a-div-width-height), which seems as though it would do the trick. Unfortunately, their 'Javascript' version actually uses the $() jquery selector to target the specific element in the DOM, based upon both its element type and class.

As vanilla JS does not allow for this, I'm unsure how to apply the solution.

The logic is confusing me where I need to target the element exactly and may have multiple instances of the same element with the same class, which all need to be processed separately.

i.e. I might have two h3 elements with the '.resize' class attached, but the first element is 50px by 100px and the second is 200px by 400px. If I simply applied the solution based on the generic element type and class ,then the css rule generated for the second element would also be applied to the first.

The only way I can think to do it is to use a unique ID for each element instead of the '.replace' class, then create an array containing the pre-defined IDs and iterate over the array to target each element. This solution is not elegant or scalable.

I have modified the function to target the `.style.fontSize` attribute using only vanilla JS, but now I get an infinite loop.

## JS:

```
function autoSize () {
  var el, elements, _i, _len, _results;
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName('resize');
  console.log(elements);
  if (elements.length < 0) {
    return;
  }
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = elements.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    el = elements[_i];
    _results.push((function(el) {
      var resizeText, _results1;
      resizeText = function() {
        var elOldFontSize = el.style.fontSize;
        var elNewFontSize;


        elNewFontSize = (parseInt(elOldFontSize.slice(0, -2)) - 1) + 'px';
        el.style.fontSize = elNewFontSize;
      };
      _results1 = [];
      while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
        _results1.push(resizeText());
      }
      return _results1;
    })(el));
  }
  return _results;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vanilla JS does not allow for this, but browser flavoured Vanilla JS does. It's called `document.querySelector` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)) and `document.querySelectorAll` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)).

Examples from the documentation:

In this example, the first element in the document with the class "myclass" is returned:

```
var el = document.querySelector(".myclass");
```

This example returns a list of all div elements within the document with a class of either "note" or "alert":

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("div.note, div.alert");
```

Comment: Ok so I would still be left with the problem that elements with the same type and class, but different size, would be targetted at once?

In which case I guess that I must use the ID selector instead. Thanks!

Comment: How are `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` _"browser flavoured Vanilla JS"_ and not _"Vanilla JS?"_

Comment: @hungerstar - Vanilla JS is basically JS without all the additions that browsers add to the `window` object. Vanilla JS doesn't have `window` object at all.

Comment: Kind of splitting hairs there. Typically _"Vanilla JS"_ means no framework/library like jQuery.

Comment: @hungerstar, I get what you mean and I agree, that was just to point out that Vanilla JS isn't what everyone thinks it is. Though technically correct is that plain JS doesn't have browser or Node.js additions.

Comment: Not sure if you're discussing semantics or some deeper level of understanding which I do not possess, but to clarify, I am referring to JS without any kind of framework, other than that which the browser provides (presumably this is why you referred to it as 'browser-flavoured').

Comment: @JoshuaFlood, that's right. That was a discussion mainly about semantics ;)

Comment: Aha np. The stackexchange seems a minefield for disagreement over semantics.

Comment: I just replaced some of the code inside the function `resizeText()` with `var elOldFontSize = el.style.fontSize; var elNewFontSize; elNewFontSize = (parseInt(elOldFontSize.slice(0, -2)) - 1) + 'px'; el.style.fontSize = elNewFontSize;` but now I'm getting an infinite loop.

I've assigned a unique ID to each element with the `.resize` class, so that is being retrieved properly.

I guess I  improperly access the `.style.fontSize` attribute for `el`. Not sure how to rectify this.